# Why is my if statement producing a key error?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have a view that simply checks for a key in the session store and if its present it will delete it and if its not present it *should* pass, it may be worth noting that the key store is holding ids of model instances.

```
def RefreshInstances(request):

    if request.session['instances']:
      del request.session['instances']
    else:
      pass

    return redirect('/')
```

This works and achieves its goal deleting the instances, however if the key store is empty I get a key error rather than the code just being passed?

Can anyone shed any light?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `request.session['instances']` throws a `KeyError` if the key is not present. I think what you want is `if 'instances' in request.session:`.

Comment: Also `else: pass` is pointless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing keys of dicts (or dictlikes) that don't exist do raise `KeyError`.

You can explicitly check for the key:

```py
if 'instances' in request.session:
   # ...
```

or you can use the `.get()` method, which returns a default value (`None` by default) if the key does not exist – this is also handy because falsy values such as 0, '', False, [] etc. pass the test:

```py
if request.session.get('instances'):
      del request.session['instances']
```

... but for deletion, simply use `.pop()` with a default and without an if:

```py
request.session.pop('instances', None)  # Remove `instances` if it's there, do nothing otherwise.
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be condensed into a single line:

```
request.session.pop('instances', None)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `request.session['instances']`, you perform a lookup. If the key (here `'instances'`) is not available, it will raise a `KeyError`. The error is thus thrown *before* the expression's truthiness is evaluated by the `if` statement.

It is however better to just use `.pop(..)` here:

```
request.session.pop('instances', None)
```

This will remove the key if it is available, and otherwise do nothing. It will return the value that was associated with the `'instances'` key, given such value exists, and return `None` otherwise.